# Preventing ArcMap from Clipping Neatline when Exporting Map

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, cartography, export

I cannot seem to keep ArcMap from clipping off a fraction of an inch on the edges of the maps I am exporting:

[image: Image of Clipped Border]

I would like the 1.5 point border that is set for the legend to be uniform around the corner of the exported image.  I've tried setting my maps inside the margins a bit and I've experimented with using much larger margins and the 'Clip Output to Graphics Extent' option on the export dialog, all to no avail.

I know this must be an easy fix, I just can't quite get my head around it.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I normally select my dataframe and right click distribute> fit to margins. This process fits the data frame to the margins of the paper size you have set. You would possibly then need to move the legend inland also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A work-around for this problem is to add a thin, near-white (or other color that closely matches your background) line outside of the neatline on all four sides of the map. The lines you add don't need to be very long.

I have not tried this in ArcGIS 10.1, but I've used this work-around many times in older versions, and in other graphics software.